# Automatically erase data from SD card

Tags: sd-card

**Is it possible to automatically format the SD card when someone put it in another PC?** 


 SD card is used in camera. And if someone wants to open that with another PC. It should be automatically formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. It would require code on the SD card that ran when inserted into a PC and could identify the PC, and the SD card standard doesn't provide for that.

Comment: Is there SD cards that can provide that?

Comment: As I said, the standard doesn't allow it, so it woudn't be SD cards if they did.